# coordinate layout with nested recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

It's the first time I am using `coordinatLayout` and I want that, when I scroll up the pic is no pushed to the action bar.

I want that when scroll recycler is in the viewport, the pic replace the label of the bar.

*XML File:*

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout

            android:id="@+id/colappsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/pink_floyd2"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="App Title" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBarTird"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/RV_posts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            >
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You can leave out the NestedScrollView as a RecyclerView is basically the same thing.

Comment: no difference between leaving nested or not i only asking about this **coordinator didn't work** why ?